# Подключение к MySQL из Delphi. Как защититься от кражи пароля?

Tags: mysql, delphi, безопасность

Решил писать небольшое онлайн-приложение на Delphi-7, или же XE5 (качается ещё). Возник вопрос соединения приложения с БД.

Слышал, что существуют компоненты для делфей, чтобы связать с мускулом. Надёжно - ли? Не поймает ли сниффер данные подключения к бд? Или же может делать всё через POST и GET и php-файла посредника? Раньше всё всегда делал при помощи POST и GET запросов и php-файла - посредника. Файл - посредник защищал лишь от POST и GET вне программы при помощи ограничения кол-ва запросов с одного IP к скрипту.

Если "лизнуть" с другой стороны, то, это ужасно ненадёжно в некоторых случаях.

Если делать всё через файл, то может есть способы защиты получше? Вообщем нужен совет в плане этого всего, т.к. будущее приложение собирается быть полностью связанным с сервером.

Answer (score 1):

Мало что понял из вашего вопроса.
Для подключения к MySQL из Delphi используйте ADO + ODBC драйвер для MySQL (есть у них на сайте).
Если при подключении пароль передается в незашифрованном виде, то снифер его словит, не важно из какой программы подключаться.